# Ruby on Rails - Simple calculations shown in the view and stored in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First of all sorry for this simple question, after spending a lot of time I have given up finding it without any help :(.

Simplified I have the following situation: one table `rates` with columns `rate` and `converted` generated with the scaffold statement within ruby. The column `rate` will be shown in the view, but the `converted` column not which will only be used in the background of the application.

Now it's my goal to ask the user for a rate given in the field `rate` so the application can calculate the `converted` and store this value in the database. It's a simple calculation: `converted` = 1 / rate.

Please advice :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are a ton of ways to do that, including but not limited to putting the logic in the model (probably cleanest), in the controller and in the view itself with a hidden field and javascript.

I would do it at the model level with a callback. For example, add this to your rates.rb model:

```
before_save :calculate_converted_rate

private

def calculate_converted_rate
  self.converted = 1.0 / self.rate
end
```

Which as the code might suggest sets the converted field to the inverse of the rate field each time before a Rates instance is saved.

More information on ActiveRecord callbacks: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 2):

Define your own mutator method in your model. This will allow you to take the input from your user, do what you want with it, then store it in the database. To illustrate:

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base

    def rate=(value)
        write_attribute :rate, value
        write_attribute :converted, 1.0 / value
    end

end
```

This will override Rails' default `rate=` method, which is what gets called when your model is passed your `rate` data from (assumedly) your form. Construct your model's form normally, with a `<%= f.text_field :rate %>` or whatever you need to do.

Note the `1.0 / value`, not `1 / value` - this will ensure the result of that expression is a float, and that you won't lose any precision. If you divide an integer by an integer in Ruby, you'll always get an integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this solution when the application needs more calculations.

Comment: +1 I like this solutions 10 times more, the value is always updated, callbacks will leave you with wrong data in the instance